# Bootstrap Capacitor Calculation

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, driver, bootstrap

In this [link](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9674-D.PDF) it explains how to calculate bootstrap capacitor for IC Mosfet Driver. In the Vboot formula as shown[image] there is Vgsmin (minimum gate source voltage). Is Vgsmin the same as Vgs or not? Before it, i used mosfet IRF3205 and IC Driver Mosfet IR2103 and Diode FR207.

Comment: There once used to be better engineers in Onsemi :( The one who decided to name "The
maximum allowable voltage drop" as Vboot is really beyond....

Answer (score 4):

You pick Vgsmin.

Vgsmin is how low you are willing to let Vgs fall before a bootstrap cap refresh. You should pick a Vgsmin no lower than that which produces the highest Rdson that you are willing to live with.

Comment: so I can freely determine the min Vgs value but shouldn't it be lower than 10V? Because the IRF 3205 datasheet Rdson 8miliohm  with Vgs = 10V @DKNguyen

Comment: Yes. I mean, you could go a bit lower but Rdson will be higher. Don't forget Rdson increases with temperature. Look at the graph later in the datasheet.

Comment: thank you @DKNguyen